# Exited on signal 11 (nginx + php-fpm)

Tags: nginx, php, segmentation-fault, coredump

I'm creating an Php Script.
This script receive some post data and process it.

I found this error in /var/log/php5-fpm.log

```
[11-May-2015 15:34:03] WARNING: [pool www] child 2553 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV - core dumped) after 6943.521858 seconds from start
[11-May-2015 15:34:03] NOTICE: [pool www] child 3882 started
```

Core Dumps:

```
warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/i386-linux gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `                                   '.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x083dce46 in ?? ()
```

gdb backtrace:

```
#0  0x083dce46 in ?? ()
#1  0x083e5074 in ?? ()
#2  0x083ed718 in ?? () 
#3  0x083e494f in ?? ()
#4  0x082c1df1 in php_log_err ()
#5  0x082c226e in ?? ()
#6  0x081c13cb in ?? ()
#7  0x0832a7b7 in zend_error ()
#8  0x083b7ff6 in ?? ()
#9  0x083b921f in ?? ()
#10 0x083957a5 in execute ()
#11 0x0832b5f9 in zend_execute_scripts ()
#12 0x082c510e in php_execute_script ()
#13 0x0806c052 in ?? ()
#14 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

nginx version: nginx/1.6.1

php version: PHP 5.4.32-2(built: Aug 25 2014 11:02:49)

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I update nginx to 1.8.0 and php to 5.4.40 (built: May  3 2015 18:09:02) but problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issues on the `php7.4.1-fpm` version on nginx with `502 bad gateway` errors.
So I updated the php-fpm version to `php7.4.3-fpm` and it fixed the issues.

Please check your php-fpm version and please update your version.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have more information about the system? An input/output error is generally not very good news and the first thing that comes to mind is a harddisk that is failing.